# how to set a new dataframe using conditions (if-else)

Tags: python, pandas

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj5wR.png)

[Error that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B270O.png)

Below are the fields of my data frame: serial, depth, x, y, z

I'm trying to find the volume (xyz) if the depth field is greater than 55, else set a default value of 6.

But I'm getting the error "Truth value of the series is ambiguous". Would someone please guide me as to where my mistake is?

```
def my_if(diamond):
    if diamond.depth > 55:
        diamond['New']= diamond.x*diamond.y*diamond.z
    else:
        diamond['New'] = 6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: So, the `diamond` that you're passing is a pandas dataframe?

Comment: It would be nice if you could post the data as text. Data in images are hard to replicate and test.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I don't think this question's a duplicate of the one you've marked. Please double-check and kindly retract your vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work. I have created a sample df `diamond` with 3 rows like your dataframe:

#### One-liner:

```
In [2041]: diamond['volume'] = np.where(diamond.depth > 55, diamond.x * diamond.y * diamond.z, 6)                                                                                    

In [2042]: diamond                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[2042]: 
   depth     x     y     z     volume
0   61.5  3.95  3.98  2.43  38.202030
1   52.8  3.89  3.84  2.31   6.000000
2   55.2  4.05  4.07  2.31  38.076885
```

#### More detailed way just for your understanding:

Step-1: Divide your dataframe into 2 parts. First, with `depth > 55`:

```
In [2004]: df1 = diamond[diamond.depth > 55]
```

Step-2: For the above obtained df1, multiply x,y and z to get volume:

```
In [2016]: df1['volume'] = df1.x * df1.y * df1.z
```

Step-3: Create another dataframe(`df2`) with `depth <= 55`:

```
In [2020]: df2 = diamond[diamond.depth <= 55]
```

Step-4: Hardcode volume to 6:

```
In [2021]: df2['volume'] = 6
```

Concat both dataframes(`df1` and `df2`) to get the complete result:

```
In [2024]: pd.concat([df1,df2])                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[2024]: 
   depth     x     y     z     volume
0   61.5  3.95  3.98  2.43  38.202030
1   59.8  3.89  3.84  2.31  34.505856
2   54.2  4.05  4.07  2.31   6.000000
```